# VBA Chart resize code not working with error: the shape is locked and cannot be resized

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

I have finally found a code that meets my needs to create a chart (Code below). However I have two problems with that:

1- Worst thing is that every time I run the code it makes 2 sheets on my workbook. One contains a blank chart frame and one contains the chart itself. The latter, thanks to the code becomes hidden but anyways, after 5 times running the code I have 10 new sheets on my workbook that have to go and delete all of them. **(This is now solved in comments below the post)**

2- I can not resize it with any resizing code that I tried. Here I have `.ChartArea.Height` and `.ChartArea.Width` which gives me the error: the shape is locked and cannot be resized.

Is there any practical way to control the size really?

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()

Charts.Add

chartarray1 = Array(Val(UserForm1.TextBox6.Value), Val(UserForm1.TextBox7.Value))
chartarray2 = Array("methane", "carbon")

Dim mychart As Chart
Dim fname As String

Set mychart = Charts.Add
With mychart
.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "emissions"
.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = chartarray2
.SeriesCollection(1).values = chartarray1
.ChartType = xlBarClustered
    .ChartArea.Height = 107
    .ChartArea.Width = 167
.ChartStyle = 6
End With


ActiveChart.Export "C:\Users\shsy\chart1.jpg"

f = activesheet.Name
Sheets(f).Select
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Visible = False

fname = "C:\Users\shsy\chart1.jpg"
UserForm1.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(fname)

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I can't test but if this is all your code, the `charts.add` line(s) might be causing it? The one at the top of the sub probably isn't needed.

Comment: That's right, the `charts.add` was indeed useless but the problem didnt solve by deleting it.

Comment: I would suggest you to not use a chart sheet, to create a chart **on the active sheet**, export it as picture, use it, then delete...

Comment: @FaneDuru, I also had this idea.  Now I export the picture (like before) and added one line `ActiveWorkbook.Charts.Delete`. Now the newly generated sheets are shot down the moment that I run the code and hence, before showing the graph I get the message : "the sheet will be permanently deleted, do you want to delete?" and I have to click yes for this question every time that I run the code.

Comment: You also use a chart sheet... Anyhow, if you like this way, you should place the code line you show between `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` and `Application.DisplayAlerts = True`. Now, it should be deleted without any warning.

Comment: @FaneDuru Thanks a lot for your help. That worked perfectly fine, and i also deleted the lines `f = activesheet.Name
Sheets(f).Select
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Visible = False` and got rid of the extra worksheet generating. So i am going to update my post and leave only the question of resizing .

Comment: @FaneDuru Could you please tell me how to edit my code to have the chart on the active sheet? I think then I can unlock the shape easier. Thanks

Comment: I am not in my office. I will show you how to do it after about 2 hours, when I will be there.

Comment: Please, test the code I pasted and send some feedback.

Comment: It might be more reliable to use `.Parent.Height` and `.Parent.Height` to resize the chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next way. It adds a chart on the active sheet, gives the possibility to play with its dimensions, save its picture and use it to place on the `UserForm1.Image1.Picture`, then delete the added chart:

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, chartarray1, chartarray2, mychart As chart, fname As String

  chartarray1 = Array(val(UserForm1.TextBox6.Value), val(UserForm1.TextBox7.Value))
  chartarray2 = Array("methane", "carbon")

 Set sh = ActiveSheet
  
 Set mychart = sh.ChartObjects.Add(left:=1, top:=10, width:=300, height:=200).chart 'play here with the chart dimensions
 With mychart
    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .SeriesCollection(1).name = "emissions"
    .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = chartarray2
    .SeriesCollection(1).Values = chartarray1
    .ChartType = xlBarClustered
        .ChartArea.height = 107
        .ChartArea.width = 167
    .ChartStyle = 6
    .Parent.Activate
 End With

 fname = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\chart1.jpg"
 ActiveChart.Export fname

 UserForm1.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(fname)
 
 'delete the created chart:
 mychart.Parent.Delete
End Sub
```

It now, saves the picture on `ThisWorkbook` (keeping this code) path. You can change it as you want.

And it is good to declare **all used variables**. Such a habit will save you from a lot of troubles in the future...

Comment: Many thanks @faneduru for your time. This code solved all my problems with the chart. Very much appreciated.